# What is IOConsoleusers: gIOScreenLockState error during boot?

Tags: startup, high-sierra, error

So yesterday morning I was using my Mac normally encoding some videos in HandBrake and installing some github repo installing some python packages system wide like a  python package named b45. Then I shutdown my Mac normally then at night when I booted my Mac it won't boot. It would boot upto 80% then a loading symbol appeared. It never booted so I checked for hardware errors then disk errors reset the smc and pram, no luck! So I booted up in verbose boot and saw the following error: **IOConsoleusers: gIOScreenLockState** I had no idea what that was so I just restored my Mac from my Time machine Backup and it boots fine. But still I am curious what this error means?

PS. I googled my question and all the answers were related to **hackintosh**. I am running High Sierra 10.13.2

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea is to update your Q with he relevant hardware details.

Comment: I agree with @LangLangC - You really need to provide your hardware details. It's not even *clear* if your Mac is in fact a hackintosh or not?

Comment: Currently, it looks like a status message, not an error, that is incomplete in itself. What came after your bolded quote in the logs?

Comment: This is happening to me as well on an iMac 2011 model running 10.13.4 beta 4. It's the last entry showing in verbose boot prior it rebooting itself. Very concerned about the computer itself as it was running sluggishly prior on both 10.13.1, 10.13.2, 10.13.3 and 10.13.4 betas. Was trying to get Apple's help on the issue, but they are incredibly slow with their bug report service (been waiting weeks) with regards to the previous issue. Now the system is spontaneously rebooting and getting this output.